# ReactJs: Unable to focus on element programmatically using React.createRef()

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, autofocus

I am trying to detect when user clicks on an arrow using the keyboard. I found this [Arrow Keys React](https://www.npmjs.com/package/arrow-keys-react) react module.

In order for it to work, I need to `focus` on a certain element. I can do this with the cursor by clicking on an element and it works fine:
[image]

[image]

But, in my app, I need to do it programmatically, so I tried this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Container } from "reactstrap";

import ArrowKeysReact from "arrow-keys-react";

export class TestComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.canvas_dom_element = React.createRef();
    this.focus = this.focus.bind(this);
    ArrowKeysReact.config({
      left: () => {
        console.log(
          " ~ file: TestComponent.js ~ line 27 ~ TestComponent ~ constructor ~ left key detected"
        );
      },
      right: () => {
        console.log(
          " ~ file: TestComponent.js ~ line 30 ~ TestComponent ~ constructor ~ right key detected."
        );
      },
      up: () => {
        console.log(
          " ~ file: TestComponent.js ~ line 36 ~ TestComponent ~ constructor ~ up key detected"
        );
      },
      down: () => {
        console.log(
          " ~ file: TestComponent.js ~ line 42 ~ TestComponent ~ constructor ~ down key detected"
        );
      },
    });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.focus();
  }
  focus() {
    // Explicitly focus the text input using the raw DOM API
    // Note: we're accessing "current" to get the DOM node
    this.canvas_dom_element.current.focus();
    console.log(
      " ~ file: TestComponent.js ~ line 199 ~ TestComponent ~ focus ~ this.canvas_dom_element.current.focus",
      this.canvas_dom_element.current.focus
    );
    console.log(
      " ~ file: TestComponent.js ~ line 199 ~ TestComponent ~ focus ~ this.canvas_dom_element.current",
      this.canvas_dom_element.current
    );
    console.log(
      " ~ file: TestComponent.js ~ line 199 ~ TestComponent ~ focus ~ this.canvas_dom_element",
      this.canvas_dom_element
    );
  }
  // Just in case component updates
  // I am trying to make sure it rerenders
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    this.focus();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <div
          tabIndex="1"
          {...ArrowKeysReact.events}
          ref={this.canvas_dom_element}
          // Testing this but it didn't work
          autoFocus
        >
          Test
        </div>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({});

const mapDispatchToProps = {};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TestComponent);
```

The `focus` function gets triggered inside `componentDidMount` and everything gets logged correctly:

[image]

But, still the element does not focused.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? It works as intended and the element keeps the focus when you press the arrows. Are you trying to focus the element when someone presses the arrows if not focused?

Comment: It seems like the div **is** focused when the component mounts, but it will loose the focus if you click elsewhere on the page.  Is that a problem?  If so, you'll need to attach your keyboard handlers to the window rather than to a specific element.

Comment: @RoboRobok Pretty sure the element is irrelevant as it was just a workaround. The goal is just to capture the arrow keys regardless of where the focus is. See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74057354/4961158).

Answer (score 0):

> In order for it to work, I need to focus on a certain element.

If I understand correctly, the desired result is that a key is always captured. The `div` is only used as a workaround because the library you're currently trying requires a focused element to work.

This is not only more complicated than it has to be, there's a (almost 100%) chance for bugs. What if the user somehow moves the focus from your div? Or your div ends up preventing other focusable elements from receiving focus when the user wants to.

Luckily you don't need to worry about focus at all.

### Use [`react-hotkeys-hook`](https://github.com/JohannesKlauss/react-hotkeys-hook) instead of `arrow-keys-react`

It does exactly what you want without needing an element. You just pass a key code, and a function that needs to run, and `deps`, if any. Your function will run every time the matching key is pressed (until the component that uses the hook unmounts).

```
import {useHotkeys} from "react-hotkeys-hook";

function App() {

  useHotkeys('left', () => {
    console.log('left key detected');
  }, []);

  useHotkeys('right', () => {
    console.log('right key detected');
  }, []);

  // ...
     
    return <div> ... </div>;
}
```

**`arrow-keys-react` hasn't had an update in 5 years**. It probably still works but it was written before hooks existed, so it's not able to provide as easy a syntax as more recent libs.

The question currently focuses on the workaround (the focus implementation detail of the current lib), rather than on the real need, which is to be able to run a function when a key is pressed ([XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)). Since the focus-part is clearly the wrong track, it's probably best to **update the title** to something like "How to detect when user presses arrow key in React".

Answer (score -1):

I tried your code and it is working correctly - element is focused when component is mounted. Not sure what is desirable behavior. ( one note just in case, when you are testing if you click on DevTools and than click on page somewhere, your element lose focus).

If you want to achieve that your element is 'always focused' which I would not recommend, you could add onBlur handler that focuses element when it looses focus (even sounds bad :)), something similar to this:

```
<div
  tabIndex="1"
  {...ArrowKeysReact.events}
  ref={this.canvas_dom_element}
  onBlur={() => {this.focus()}}
  // Testing this but it didn't work
  autoFocus
>
  Test
</div>
```

Comment: Literally never do this